# failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Tags: rust, stm32ldiscovery

I'm following this `https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/03-setup/index.html` while installing `itmdump` through `cargo install itm --vers 0.3.1`  , it throws an error `error: failed to fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index  Caused by:
  error inflating zlib stream; class=Zlib (5)`
How could this error be resolved ?

Comment: Make sure you're online, with access to GitHub, and that you don't have a virus/antivirus or other malware that intercepts HTTPS connections. This looks like either a network error, or some bug/corruption in Cargo or your system's zlib library. Try running `cargo update` again. If that doesn't help, reinstall Rust/Cargo. If that doesn't help, file bugs.